# Kendo React Bootstrap Datepicker year not clickable

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, react-bootstrap, kendo-datepicker, kendo-react-ui

I am using Kendo DatePicker control in React Bootstrap. It seems to be working fine, but when I try to change the year it is not working. I am using React 16+ and Bootstrap 3.3.

below is the scrrenshot for same

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try updating the packages. It is clickable with the latest version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7ae58b?file=index.html